# yii2 fullcalendar : Show all event in month view, and just some event in weeks view

Tags: jquery, yii2, fullcalendar

i have an event that have confirmation attribute (confirmed or unconfirmed) :

```
$event  = Event::find()->all();

foreach ($event as $opo) {
$event = new yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
...
$event->title = $opo->confirm;
...
$data[] = $event;
}
```

index.php:

```
 <?= yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
'events'=>$events,
],
));
```

I Want to show **all** of my event in a month view and show only **confirmed** event in basicWeek view.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: I think you'd have to handle the viewRender callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) and add/remove events at that stage. It might be easier to have two event sources - one for confirmed events and one for others, and just add the "others" source when the view type is "month", and remove it again when it isn't.

Comment: @ADyson, Thank you. can you give me an example code ?, i dont know how to implement that logic.

Comment: Which part is difficult for you? Do you understand about event sources? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/ . Basically you split your current event feed into two feeds, then you can switch the feeds on and off as needed in the calendar. The rest is just a trivial use of `if` statements to do the switching. (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/ to actually do the adding/removing of the source each time)